# $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}$-calculus for quadratic form

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I've been working through [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835) set of notes on differentials of $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions of complex variables (and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661028/gradient-vector-and-hessian-matrix-of-function-containing-vector-of-complex-expo) MSE question), and I'm trying to work through a simple example. Do I have the following terminology and computations right, or have I messed up something?

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $A = A^{\top}$. Define $z := r e^{j \theta}$ and $f(z) := \frac{1}{2} z^H A z$. For the differential of $f$ with respect to $x$ for $x = (r,\theta)$, we have operators
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\cdot) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}(\cdot) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial r}(\cdot) = e^{j\theta} \odot \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\cdot) + e^{-j\theta} \odot \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}(\cdot) \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\cdot) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}(\cdot) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial \theta}(\cdot) = j r e^{j\theta} \odot \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\cdot) - j r e^{-j\theta} \odot \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}(\cdot) \tag{2}
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f = e^{j\theta} \odot \frac{1}{2} z^H A + \frac{1}{2} e^{-j\theta} \odot Az \tag{3}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f = \frac{1}{2} j z \odot \frac{1}{2} z^H A + \frac{1}{2} j z \odot Az \tag{4}.
$$

1. Is it correct to say that the operators in (1) and (2) are nonlinear because $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\cdot)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}(\cdot)$ are nonlinear (see eq. 20 and 51 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835))?
2. Is the $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}$-Hessian w.r.t. $r$ and $\theta$ found by just applying (1) and (2) to the parts of (3) and (4) involving $z$, and normal $\mathbb{R}$-calculus to the parts involving $r$ and $\theta$?